# Is there a tool to help find the 'distance' between two Ethereum addresses?

Tags: explorers

I.e., if A has sent to B, distance = 1. If A has sent to B and B has sent to C, distance between A and C is 2.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to parse the entire blockchain and construct a graph where nodes are addresses and edges are direct transactions between two accounts. Then you would perform Dijkstra's algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

As per Sasa's answer, you'd need to generate a dataset that could then be interpreted in the appropriate way.

Instead of generating your own from the raw chain data, you could use something like [Google's BigQuery public Ethereum dataset](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/ethereum-bigquery-public-dataset-smart-contract-analytics) and run the appropriate query. (You'll need to enable the Cloud Platform API before you can browse the public datasets.)

It looks like the dataset was last updated on 4 Mar 2019, but there are instructions on how it was generated, [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/ethereum-bigquery-how-we-built-dataset), so it may be possible to copy the public data and update it.

For existing examples of what can be done with the BigQuery data, see this clustering study: [Clustering Ethereum Addresses](https://towardsdatascience.com/clustering-ethereum-addresses-18aeca61919d). This used different measures of distance between addresses (e.g. Euclidean and cosine distances<sup>1</sup>) to categorise addresses into connected clusters.

There are probably better existing tools out there, such as the ones used by chain analysis/forensics groups.

<sup>1</sup> More on distances in data science, [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/9-distance-measures-in-data-science-918109d069fa).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bitquery's [Coinpath API](https://docs.bitquery.io/v1/docs/building-queries/Coinpath%20Explained/Overview).

It helps you follow money and blockchain.

And provide details on relationships between the two addresses

For example, check [this API](https://ide.bitquery.io/Relation-between-two-address)

[image: Relation between two addresses]

You can also check this on their [blockchain explorer](https://explorer.bitquery.io/).

For example, in [this money flow visualization](https://explorer.bitquery.io/ethereum/address/0xa09871aeadf4994ca12f5c0b6056bbd1d343c029/graph?from=2018-03-01&till=2021-01-31), you can see the money flow from the Upbit hack. (Click on Sankey radio button)

Answer (score -2):

the true measurement between two addresses would be a subtraction of one from another, like this:

```
address1 := common.HexToAddress("0x.......")
address2 := common.HexToAddress("0x.......")
big_a1 := new(big.Int)
big_a2 := new(big.Int)
big_a1.SetBytes(address1.Bytes())
big_a2.SetBytes(address2.Bytes())
big_diff := new(big.Int)
big_diff.Sub(big_a2,big_a1)
fmt.Printf("difference = %v\n",big_diff.String())
```

imports:

```
math/big
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. This is something totally different

Comment: @LauriPeltonen if you don't see it, it is not my problem. The answer is correct.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen I think he's trolling :)

Comment: @SasaMilic I am not trolling, he asked about distance between addresses, not transactions. Since address is a number the distance between two numbers is subtraction operation. the OP didn't formulate question correctly, the correct formulation would be "transactional distance between addresses".

Comment: He explicitly says *if A has sent to B, distance = 1*.

Comment: @Ismael this isn't the same as explicitly saying "amount transactions between two addresses"